# ctags support for MooseX::Declare? (Perl)

Tags: perl, editor, moose, ctags, exuberant-ctags

How can I get ctags to generate tags for MooseX::Declare methods, classes, attributes and such?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a list of regular expressions that you can add to your ctags syntax file/command:

http://www.abstractwankery.com/2010/02/moosexdeclare-textmate-and-tmcod/94

Comment: Archived at https://web.archive.org/web/20110903042738/http://www.abstractwankery.com/2010/02/moosexdeclare-textmate-and-tmcod/94